# ASP.NET Hide and show divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I know that there are alot of solutions. But i already tried to follow every step and still didnt worked out!This is my code

```
<div id="quadrado1" onclick='$("perfil1").show()'>
   <img src="images/perfilbackground/vermelho.png" alt=""/>
         <div id="perfil1" hidden="hidden">
           <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
           <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
           <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"/>
           <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

The div perfil1 was suppose be hidden and when i clicked on "quadrado1" it supposedly should show the div! Any ideias?

**EDIT**

It seems that i forgot to put the jquery script

```
´<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>´
```

Comment: `$("perfil1").show()` You're not calling the id properly. It should be `$("#perfil1").show()`

Comment: Missing perfil1 closing div tag

Answer (score 1):

Change this div to:

```
<div id="perfil1" style="display:none">
```

Calling `show()` alters the display attribute.  As @DrewKennedy mentioned, you also need the # before the ID.

Answer (score 0):

You had hide the div using hidden property and want to show using display property that is why it is not working. Please try below solution it is working

```
<div id="quadrado1" onclick='$("#perfil1").show()'>
   <img src="images/perfilbackground/vermelho.png" alt=""/>
    <div id="perfil1" style="display: none;">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is there anything different in this than from the already given answer which is commented as not working.

Comment: This is working on my machine may be he is not able to understand what already answered that is why I provide complete answer with code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this--

In **Html**

```
<div id="quadrado1">
  <img src="images/perfilbackground/vermelho.png" alt=""/>
  <div id="perfil1" style="display: none;">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>
</div>
```

In Script

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#quadrado1").click(function(){
        $("#perfil1").show();
     })
   })
</script>
```